# Select element with lowest value from multiple joins in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

How to select some data sets with group by and multiple joins? I've read about [sub queries or left join approaches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), but unfortunately I can't combine it with my other needs. My problem is, that I get either entries form other clients or entries without a full relation between the 2 tables. Or the right entries on the left, but not with the lowest values on the right. Or even totally different data which I can't understand why.

### Expected results

For example I need the cheapest (`price_consumer`) motor for every model (`model_id`) of `client_id = 1000` and `country_id = 1` and `pricelist_id = 20`. Most relevant data is in the table `cc_pricelist_elements`. Here the col `fk_table` is relevant as only rows are interesting where it has the value ***motors***. Models without a corresponding entry in the cc_pricelist_elements shouldn't be part of the result.

At the same time, the name of the according model from the `cc_models` table is required.

A result set (out of the data given below) would look like:

```
cc_models.name | cc_pricelist_elements.price_consumer
---------------|-------------------------------------
Model 2016     | 150
```

Of course, there could be more models per client (n:1) and many motors per model (

### Database structure and sample data

**Edit:** [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce3f1/1) with simplified table structure and reduced data.

I put some more tables here because I am not sure if they are necessary for the query since they are partially related to each other.

[image]

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;

-- Dumping structure for table audaris_central.cc_lines
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cc_lines` (
  `client_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `line_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`,`line_id`),
  KEY `line_id` (`line_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

-- Dumping data for table audaris_central.cc_lines: ~11 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cc_lines` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `cc_lines` (`client_id`, `line_id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1000, 3, 'Standart'),
    (1000, 4, 'Luxus5'),
    (1000, 5, 'Standard Plus'),
    (1000, 12, 'Comfortline'),
    (1000, 13, 'Trendline'),
    (1000, 14, 'Highline'),
    (1438, 6, 'Trendline'),
    (1577, 10, 'Trendline'),
    (1604, 15, 'Trikolor'),
    (1634, 8, 'Standard'),
    (1634, 9, 'Executive');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cc_lines` ENABLE KEYS */;


-- Dumping structure for table audaris_central.cc_meta_lines_models
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cc_meta_lines_models` (
  `model_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `line_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`model_id`,`line_id`),
  KEY `fk_line_id` (`line_id`),
  KEY `fk_model_id` (`model_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_line_id` FOREIGN KEY (`line_id`) REFERENCES `cc_lines` (`line_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_model_id` FOREIGN KEY (`model_id`) REFERENCES `cc_models` (`model_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Dumping data for table audaris_central.cc_meta_lines_models: ~23 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cc_meta_lines_models` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `cc_meta_lines_models` (`model_id`, `line_id`) VALUES
    (20, 3),
    (20, 4),
    (22, 3),
    (22, 4),
    (23, 4),
    (23, 5),
    (29, 8),
    (31, 6),
    (34, 8),
    (35, 8),
    (36, 8),
    (36, 9),
    (38, 8),
    (39, 8),
    (39, 9),
    (41, 10),
    (43, 8),
    (46, 8),
    (47, 9),
    (54, 12),
    (54, 13),
    (54, 14),
    (57, 15);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cc_meta_lines_models` ENABLE KEYS */;


-- Dumping structure for table audaris_central.cc_meta_motors_variants
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cc_meta_motors_variants` (
  `motor_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `variant_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`motor_id`,`variant_id`),
  KEY `motor_id` (`motor_id`),
  KEY `variant_id` (`variant_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_cc_meta_motors_variants_cc_motors` FOREIGN KEY (`motor_id`) REFERENCES `cc_motors` (`motor_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_cc_meta_motors_variants_cc_variants` FOREIGN KEY (`variant_id`) REFERENCES `cc_variants` (`variant_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

-- Dumping data for table audaris_central.cc_meta_motors_variants: ~4 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cc_meta_motors_variants` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `cc_meta_motors_variants` (`motor_id`, `variant_id`) VALUES
    (6, 22),
    (6, 25),
    (6, 50),
    (8, 22);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cc_meta_motors_variants` ENABLE KEYS */;


-- Dumping structure for table audaris_central.cc_models
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cc_models` (
  `client_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `model_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `original_model_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`,`model_id`),
  KEY `model_id` (`model_id`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=59 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

-- Dumping data for table audaris_central.cc_models: ~34 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cc_models` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `cc_models` (`client_id`, `model_id`, `original_model_id`, `name`) VALUES
    (287, 45, 1329, 'MJ2016'),
    (1000, 11, 1501, NULL),
    (1000, 12, 1501, NULL),
    (1000, 19, 2317, 'test'),
    (1000, 20, 2288, 'Modell 2016'),
    (1000, 21, 2312, '123456'),
    (1000, 22, 2288, 'Modell 2015'),
    (1000, 23, 2290, 'Modell 2015'),
    (1000, 25, 2289, 'normal'),
    (1000, 32, 1503, 'Modell 2016'),
    (1000, 33, 1500, NULL),
    (1000, 54, 2255, 'Modell 2016'),
    (1000, 56, 2256, '2016'),
    (1438, 31, 2255, '2SJ4A3'),
    (1562, 44, 1500, 'Highline'),
    (1577, 41, 2253, '2016'),
    (1602, 55, 1501, NULL),
    (1604, 57, 1973, 'Modell 2015'),
    (1631, 58, 2286, NULL),
    (1634, 29, 2288, 'Modell 2015'),
    (1634, 34, 2291, 'Modell 2016'),
    (1634, 35, 2290, 'Modell 2016'),
    (1634, 36, 2307, 'Modell 2016'),
    (1634, 38, 2295, 'Modell 2016'),
    (1634, 39, 2308, 'Modell 2016'),
    (1634, 43, 2297, 'Modell 2016'),
    (1634, 46, 2288, 'Modell 2016'),
    (1634, 47, 2301, 'Modell 2016'),
    (1634, 48, 2303, 'Modell 2016'),
    (1634, 49, 2312, NULL),
    (1634, 50, 2313, NULL),
    (1634, 51, 2195, NULL),
    (1634, 52, 2317, NULL),
    (1634, 53, 2304, 'Modell 2016');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cc_models` ENABLE KEYS */;


-- Dumping structure for table audaris_central.cc_motors
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cc_motors` (
  `client_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `motor_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `variant_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `gears` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `gearbox` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `drive` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `kw` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cylinders` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `engine_size` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fuel` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ees` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'exhaust emission standard',
  `eec` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'energy efficiency class',
  `emission` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `consumption_combined` decimal(3,1) unsigned DEFAULT '0.0',
  `consumption_urban` decimal(3,1) unsigned DEFAULT '0.0',
  `consumption_extraurban` decimal(3,1) unsigned DEFAULT '0.0',
  `weight` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `e10` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `superplus` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `code` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`motor_id`,`client_id`),
  KEY `variant_id` (`variant_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=38 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Dumping data for table audaris_central.cc_motors: ~27 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cc_motors` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `cc_motors` (`client_id`, `motor_id`, `variant_id`, `name`, `gears`, `gearbox`, `drive`, `kw`, `cylinders`, `engine_size`, `fuel`, `ees`, `eec`, `emission`, `consumption_combined`, `consumption_urban`, `consumption_extraurban`, `weight`, `e10`, `superplus`, `code`) VALUES
    (1000, 6, 0, '3,0 JTDxy', 6, 1, 1, 117, 4, 2998, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ''),
    (1000, 7, 0, 'FIAT DUCATO SPECIAL X250 - motor 2.0 JTD - 115 PS', 5, 1, 1, 85, 4, 2000, 1, 5, 'A+', 150, 9.5, 11.0, 8.5, 3500, NULL, NULL, 'X250'),
    (1000, 8, 0, 'FIAT Ducato EURO5 2,30 Multijet 16V 130 CV - 35 QL', 6, 1, 1, 96, 4, 2300, 1, 5, 'B', 0, 10.4, 11.9, 9.9, 3620, NULL, NULL, ''),
    (1000, 9, 0, 'FIAT DUCATO SPECIAL X250 - motor 2.0 JTD - 115 PS', 5, 1, 1, 85, 4, 2000, 1, 5, 'A+', 150, 9.5, 11.0, 8.5, 3500, NULL, NULL, 'X250'),
    (1634, 10, 0, 'FIAT 180 Multijet Power', 6, 1, 1, 130, 4, 2999, 2, 0, 'B', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, NULL, NULL, 'FIAT 180 CV'),
    (1438, 13, 0, '2,0TDI', 6, 1, 1, 110, 4, 1968, 2, 6, 'A', 150, 10.0, 8.0, 9.0, 2000, NULL, NULL, '123456'),
    (1577, 17, 0, '2.0 TDI SCR BMT 62kW / 84PS', 5, 1, 1, 62, 4, 1968, 2, 6, 'B', 155, 6.0, 7.1, 5.3, 2087, NULL, NULL, ''),
    (1577, 18, 0, '2.0 TDI SCR BMT 75kW / 102PS', 5, 1, 1, 75, 4, 1968, 2, 6, 'B', 155, 6.0, 7.1, 5.3, 2087, NULL, NULL, ''),
    (1577, 19, 0, '2.0 TDI SCR 110kW / 150PS', 6, 1, 1, 110, 4, 1968, 2, 6, 'B', 161, 6.2, 7.4, 5.5, 2117, NULL, NULL, ''),
    (1577, 20, 0, '2.0 TDI SCR 4Motion 110kW / 150PS', 6, 1, 3, 110, 4, 1968, 2, 6, 'B', 171, 6.6, 7.8, 5.9, 2267, NULL, NULL, ''),
    (1577, 21, 0, '2.0 TDI SCR DSG BMT 110kW / 150PS', 7, 3, 1, 110, 4, 1968, 2, 6, 'A', 155, 6.0, 6.7, 5.6, 2141, NULL, NULL, ''),
    (1577, 22, 0, '2.0 TDI SCR DSG 4Motion 110kW / 150PS', 7, 3, 3, 110, 4, 1968, 2, 6, 'A', 163, 6.3, 7.0, 5.9, 2286, NULL, NULL, ''),
    (1577, 23, 0, '2.0 TSI 110kW / 150PS', 6, 1, 1, 110, 4, 1984, 1, 6, 'D', 210, 9.2, 12.3, 7.5, 2113, NULL, NULL, ''),
    (1634, 24, 0, 'FIAT 115 Multijet', 5, 1, 1, 85, 4, 1958, 2, 5, 'D', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, NULL, NULL, 'FIAT 115 CV'),
    (1634, 25, 0, 'FIAT 130 Multijet', 6, 1, 1, 96, 4, 2287, 2, 5, 'D', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, NULL, NULL, 'FIAT 130 CV'),
    (1634, 26, 0, 'FIAT 150 Multijet', 6, 1, 1, 110, 4, 2287, 2, 5, 'C', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, NULL, NULL, 'FIAT 150 CV'),
    (1634, 27, 0, 'VW 2,0 TDI 140', 5, 1, 1, 103, 4, 1968, 2, 6, 'B', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, NULL, NULL, 'VW 140 CV'),
    (1634, 28, 0, 'Mercedes Sprinter 316 CD', 6, 1, 1, 118, 4, 2143, 2, 6, 'B', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, NULL, NULL, 'MB 316 CD'),
    (287, 29, 0, '1.0 EcoTSI', 6, 1, 1, 81, 3, 999, 1, 6, 'B', 99, 4.3, 5.2, 3.8, 1109, 1, NULL, ''),
    (1634, 30, 0, 'FIAT 150 Multijet', 6, 1, 1, 110, 4, 2287, 2, 5, 'C', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, NULL, NULL, 'FIAT 150 CV'),
    (1634, 31, 0, 'FIAT 115 Multijet', 5, 1, 1, 85, 4, 1958, 2, 5, 'D', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, NULL, NULL, 'FIAT 115 CV'),
    (1634, 32, 0, 'FIAT 115 Multijet', 5, 1, 1, 85, 4, 1958, 2, 5, 'D', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, NULL, NULL, 'FIAT 115 CV'),
    (1634, 33, 0, 'FIAT 150 Multijet', 6, 1, 1, 110, 4, 2287, 2, 5, 'C', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, NULL, NULL, 'FIAT 150 CV'),
    (1634, 34, 0, 'FIAT 180 Multijet Power', 6, 1, 1, 130, 4, 2999, 2, 0, 'B', 0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0, NULL, NULL, 'FIAT 180 CV'),
    (1000, 35, 0, '2,0 TDI 110 KW', 6, 1, 1, 110, 4, 1986, 2, 6, 'B', 145, 8.9, 15.0, 11.0, 2413, NULL, NULL, ''),
    (1000, 36, 0, '2,0 TDI 110 KW DSG', 6, 3, 1, 110, 4, 1986, 2, 6, 'B', 145, 8.9, 15.0, 11.0, 2413, NULL, NULL, ''),
    (1604, 37, 0, '1.6 GDI 6-Gang 99 kW (135 PS)', 6, 1, 1, 99, 4, 1591, 1, 6, 'C', 140, 6.2, 8.1, 5.1, 1294, NULL, NULL, 'TMA');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cc_motors` ENABLE KEYS */;


-- Dumping structure for table audaris_central.cc_pricelists
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cc_pricelists` (
  `client_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pricelist_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `variant_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`,`pricelist_id`),
  KEY `variant_id` (`variant_id`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
  KEY `pricelist_id` (`pricelist_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Dumping data for table audaris_central.cc_pricelists: ~8 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cc_pricelists` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `cc_pricelists` (`client_id`, `pricelist_id`, `variant_id`, `name`) VALUES
    (287, 16, 34, 'Ibiza MJ2016'),
    (1000, 9, 15, 'Preisliste 1'),
    (1000, 20, 50, 'test2'),
    (1438, 10, 24, 'Multivan Trendline 2016'),
    (1577, 14, 31, 'VW T6 Multivan Trendline 2016'),
    (1634, 17, 40, 'Brownie 1'),
    (1634, 18, 43, 'Oasi 540'),
    (1634, 19, 45, 'Oasi 610 N');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cc_pricelists` ENABLE KEYS */;


-- Dumping structure for table audaris_central.cc_pricelist_elements
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cc_pricelist_elements` (
  `pricelist_element_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pricelist_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `line_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fk_table` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `fk_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cost` decimal(10,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `price_catalog` decimal(10,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `price_consumer` decimal(10,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `price_dealer` decimal(10,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `is_available` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_standard` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `is_default` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`,`pricelist_id`,`fk_table`,`fk_id`,`line_id`,`country_id`),
  KEY `pricelist_element_id` (`pricelist_element_id`),
  KEY `client_id_pricelist_id_line_id_country_id` (`client_id`,`pricelist_id`,`line_id`,`country_id`),
  KEY `FK_cc_pricelist_elements_cc_pricelists` (`pricelist_id`),
  KEY `fk_table` (`fk_table`),
  KEY `fk_id` (`fk_id`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`),
  KEY `line_id` (`line_id`),
  KEY `is_available` (`is_available`),
  KEY `client_id_line_id_is_available` (`client_id`,`line_id`,`is_available`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_cc_pricelist_elements_cc_pricelists` FOREIGN KEY (`pricelist_id`) REFERENCES `cc_pricelists` (`pricelist_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=134 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Dumping data for table audaris_central.cc_pricelist_elements: ~26 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cc_pricelist_elements` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `cc_pricelist_elements` (`pricelist_element_id`, `client_id`, `pricelist_id`, `line_id`, `country_id`, `fk_table`, `fk_id`, `cost`, `price_catalog`, `price_consumer`, `price_dealer`, `is_available`, `is_standard`, `is_default`) VALUES
    (118, 1000, 20, 12, 1, 'colors', 35, 0.0000, 228.0000, 96.0000, 0.0000, 1, NULL, 0),
    (128, 1000, 20, 12, 1, 'equipments', 3, 0.0000, 212.0000, 83.0000, 0.0000, 1, 0, 0),
    (129, 1000, 20, 12, 1, 'equipments', 8, 0.0000, 275.0000, 214.0000, 0.0000, 1, 0, 0),
    (122, 1000, 20, 12, 1, 'equipments', 129, 0.0000, 638.0000, 510.0000, 0.0000, 1, 0, 0),
    (117, 1000, 20, 14, 1, 'equipments', 129, 0.0000, 468.0000, 401.0000, 0.0000, 0, 1, 0),
    (123, 1000, 20, 12, 1, 'interiors', 7, 0.0000, 327.0000, 165.0000, 0.0000, 1, NULL, 0),
    (127, 1000, 20, 12, 1, 'interiors', 8, 0.0000, 131.0000, 110.0000, 0.0000, 1, NULL, 0),
    (130, 1000, 20, 12, 1, 'motors', 6, 0.0000, 476.0000, 448.0000, 0.0000, 1, NULL, 0),
    (133, 1000, 20, 13, 1, 'motors', 6, 0.0000, 0.0000, 150.0000, 0.0000, 0, NULL, 0),
    (120, 1000, 20, 12, 1, 'motors', 35, 0.0000, 985.0000, 895.0000, 0.0000, 1, NULL, 0),
    (121, 1000, 20, 12, 1, 'motors', 36, 0.0000, 702.0000, 529.0000, 0.0000, 1, NULL, 0),
    (41, 1438, 10, 12, 1, 'motors', 13, 0.0000, 456.0000, 949.0000, 0.0000, 1, NULL, 0),
    (80, 1577, 14, 10, 1, 'equipments', 19, 0.0000, 972.0000, 845.0000, 0.0000, 1, 0, 0),
    (79, 1577, 14, 10, 1, 'motors', 19, 0.0000, 697.0000, 674.0000, 0.0000, 0, NULL, 0),
    (110, 1577, 14, 10, 2, 'motors', 19, 0.0000, 468.0000, 323.0000, 0.0000, 0, NULL, 0),
    (99, 1634, 17, 9, 1, 'colors', 9, 0.0000, 152.0000, 85.0000, 0.0000, 1, NULL, 1),
    (101, 1634, 17, 9, 1, 'colors', 32, 0.0000, 155.0000, 46.0000, 0.0000, 1, NULL, 0),
    (96, 1634, 17, 9, 1, 'equipments', 18, 0.0000, 217.0000, 62.0000, 500.0000, 1, 0, 0),
    (102, 1634, 17, 9, 1, 'interiors', 1, 0.0000, 523.0000, 462.0000, 0.0000, 0, NULL, 1),
    (105, 1634, 17, 9, 1, 'motors', 10, 0.0000, 967.0000, 919.0000, 0.0000, 1, NULL, 0),
    (103, 1634, 17, 9, 1, 'motors', 24, 0.0000, 466.0000, 398.0000, 0.0000, 0, NULL, 1),
    (106, 1634, 17, 9, 1, 'motors', 25, 0.0000, 230.0000, 225.0000, 0.0000, 1, NULL, 0),
    (104, 1634, 17, 9, 1, 'motors', 26, 0.0000, 553.0000, 519.0000, 0.0000, 1, NULL, 0),
    (107, 1634, 19, 8, 1, 'motors', 32, 0.0000, 175.0000, 10.0000, 0.0000, 0, NULL, 1),
    (108, 1634, 19, 8, 1, 'motors', 33, 0.0000, 916.0000, 782.0000, 0.0000, 1, NULL, 0),
    (109, 1634, 19, 8, 1, 'motors', 34, 0.0000, 358.0000, 174.0000, 0.0000, 1, NULL, 0);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cc_pricelist_elements` ENABLE KEYS */;


-- Dumping structure for table audaris_central.cc_variants
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cc_variants` (
  `client_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `variant_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`client_id`,`variant_id`,`model_id`),
  KEY `variant_id` (`variant_id`),
  KEY `model_id` (`model_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

-- Dumping data for table audaris_central.cc_variants: ~19 rows (approximately)
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cc_variants` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT IGNORE INTO `cc_variants` (`client_id`, `variant_id`, `model_id`, `name`) VALUES
    (287, 34, 45, 'FR'),
    (1000, 9, 19, 'Reisemobil (Kastenwagen)'),
    (1000, 16, 23, 'Standard'),
    (1000, 22, 11, 'Gelbgrün'),
    (1000, 25, 32, 'Kombi'),
    (1000, 50, 54, 'Kombi'),
    (1438, 24, 31, 'Kombi'),
    (1577, 31, 41, 'Großraumlimousine'),
    (1604, 52, 57, 'Kombi'),
    (1634, 40, 47, 'Wohnmobil'),
    (1634, 41, 43, 'Wohnmobil'),
    (1634, 42, 29, 'Wohnmobil'),
    (1634, 43, 46, 'Wohnmobil'),
    (1634, 44, 35, 'Wohnmobil'),
    (1634, 45, 34, 'Wohnmobil'),
    (1634, 46, 38, 'Wohnmobil'),
    (1634, 47, 36, 'Wohnmobil'),
    (1634, 48, 39, 'Wohnmobil'),
    (1634, 49, 48, 'Wohnwagen/Caravan');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `cc_variants` ENABLE KEYS */;
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=IFNULL(@OLD_SQL_MODE, '') */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=IF(@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS IS NULL, 1, @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS) */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

### Approach

This is what I came up with so far (best approach), but the result is far away from what is desired.

```
SELECT
    ccm.model_id, ccm.name, ccpe.price_consumer
FROM
    cc_models ccm
INNER JOIN
    cc_meta_lines_models cclm ON
    cclm.model_id = ccm.model_id
INNER JOIN
    cc_pricelist_elements ccpe ON
    ccpe.client_id = 1000 AND
    ccpe.fk_table = 'motors' AND
    ccpe.country_id = 1 AND
    ccpe.pricelist_id = 20
LEFT JOIN
    cc_pricelist_elements ccpe2 ON
    ccpe2.pricelist_element_id = ccpe.pricelist_element_id AND
    ccpe.price_consumer < ccpe2.price_consumer
WHERE
    ccm.client_id = 1000 AND
    ccpe2.pricelist_element_id IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    ccm.name
```

Comment: How about a sqlfiddle with some sample data?

Comment: Than add just a part of the data that is relevant to the issue.

Comment: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce3f1/1)  with reduced data structure now is added to the question

Comment: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max discusses how to get such.